# Jordan canonical form of $T: \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and $T$ is multiplication by $\alpha$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, jordan-normal-form

Suppose $p \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $p$. Then consider the linear transformation $T : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, $x \mapsto \alpha x$.

What is the Jordan canonical form of $T$, considering $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ to be a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space?

Suppose $\deg(p) = n$ and $p = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ has dimension $n$ with basis $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \cdots, \alpha^{n}\}$. Moreover, obviously the transformation $T$ acts on the basis element as $\alpha^i \mapsto \alpha^{i+1}$ for $i < n-1$. But $\alpha^{n-1} \mapsto \alpha^n = -a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1} - \cdots - a_1\alpha - a_0$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Thus $T$ is represented by the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix), $C_p$

Not sure what the next steps would be- I'm confusing myself a bit here. It is well known that the companion matrix $C_p$'s characteristic and minimal polynomial is $p$ itself. Moreover, we know that $\alpha$ is thus an eigenvalue, which means that $\bar{\alpha}$ is as well. Thus $(x-\alpha)(x-\bar{\alpha}) | p$. One *cannot* conclude at this point that since $p$ is irreducible, $(x-\alpha)(x-\bar{\alpha}) = p$, since it is possible that $(x- \alpha)(x-\bar{\alpha}) \in \mathbb{R}[x]\setminus \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Even if $p = (x-\alpha)(x-\bar{\alpha})$ after all, I'm still a bit confused. Now that we've expanded our scope to $\mathbb{C}$, it's pretty clear that $\alpha$ is the *only* eigenvalue, so would the JCF simply be $\alpha I$? I'm getting a bit confused with the JCF since we traditionally start with an algebraically closed field and $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't. Would appreciate some help - I believe the intent is to proceed as if $C_p \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Jordan form over what field? Over $\mathbb{C}$? Since an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is squarefree, the minimal/characteristic polynomial of the companion matrix splits and is squarefree over $\mathbb{C}$, hence the Jordan form is diagonal and contains just the roots of $p(x)$. For a Jordan form, you only need the characteristic polynomial to split, so all you need is to be working onver the splitting field of $p(x)$.

Comment: A matrix $A$ has a Jordan form over the field $F$ (assuming $A$ is defined over $F$) if and only if the characteristic polynomial of $A$ splits over $F$. This happens for *any* matrix over $\mathbb{C}$, but you can always ask whether a particular matrix happens to have a Jordan form over any field. In this case, the least field over which there is a form is the splitting field.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$. I stated this in the comment to @markvs answer, but basically I'm confused about the irreducibility in $\mathbb{Q}$ 'transferring' to $\mathbb{C}$. Is it not possible that $(x-\alpha)^2 | p$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ but $(x-\alpha)^2 \not \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ retaining the irreducibility of $p$.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Irreducible polynomials over the rationals never have multiple roots. Look up "separability", or note that a polynomial has multiple roots in its splitting field if and only if $\gcd(p,p')\neq 1$ (where $p'$ is the formal derivative). Because $p$ is irreducible and $p'\neq 0$, $\gcd(p,p')=1$, so $p$ has no multiple root sin $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p$ is irreducible every root  of it has multiplicity $1$. Hence the Jordan form is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: I hope I'm not being silly here but $\alpha$ is complex, and $p$ was merely chosen as irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Is it not possible that $(x-\alpha)^2 | p$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ but $(x-\alpha)^2 \not \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ retaining the irreducibility of $p$.

Comment: If $p$ has multiple complex root, then it has a common nontrivial divisor with its derivative, and so it is not irreducible over $\mathbb Q$..